# Getting the error in Jenkins console java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15

Tags: jenkins, gradle

***Task I am doing***
I am trying to trigger Junit using gradle in Jenkins. I am using powerMock (1.4.12) + mockito (1.9.5) for mocking along with Junit4 (4.11) & java8.

***The problem***
Getting the error in Jenkin console                        java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15

***JUnit Report below stack trace***

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name amdocs.APILink.backend.services.arCrgAdjnRef00. Reason: null at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:266)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: Do you miss something from your question? The exception from the title is nowhere in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not use libraries / tools that are **five** years old, when there are newer versions. Either this is a bug in one of the tools you use, or something got added to Java as language that they don't understand.

Comment: So? As I said there might be a bug in the tool or some feature added to the language that the tool simply does not know about. e. g. the invokedynamic instruction.